# Firefox spamming mouseenter event with jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, firefox

In Firefox, for some odd reason, when animating (via jQuery) an object inside of a mouseenter or mouseover event, the event is spammed while simply hovering over the element. If you move the mouse, it spams quicker (obviously more events firing). This ONLY happens in Firefox and only when using an animation call.

Here's a fiddle which demonstrates the issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/52EKC/3/

```
/* CSS */
body {
    font-family: consolas;
}
#testarea {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}



<!-- HTML -->
<textarea id='testarea'></textarea><br/>
Event Fired: <span id='counter'>0</span> times



// JavaScript
var i = 0;
$('#testarea').on('mouseenter', function() {
   $('#counter').text(++i);
   $(this).animate({ width: 299 }, 200);
});
```

Any workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
It appears this bug is only with text areas and text boxes. If I replace the text area with a div, the event only fires once, as expected. Because I'm using text-areas, I need to find a work-around. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the  `$(this).animate({ width: 299 }, 200);`
if you comment it out, it works perfectly

Comment: Umm... That defeats the entire point of my post. When animating an input object, there should not be a rapid fire of the mouseenter event.